# Joomla bugging out with status 200 but blank screen no errors

Tags: debugging, joomla

When I set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Hundreds of warnings and strict messages but no errors, locally it works but not on site. When I make a GET request it works but same url sending a POST request doesn't work.

I think it's some plugin causing this but hard to track down when Joomla happily gives me a blank page with 200 response.

In firebug I can't see the response, it only gives me:

> Reload the page to get source for: the_url

This is in the /components/com_doctrine/doctrine.php

```
$route=JRequest::getVar('router', 'Tournament');
$controllerName = 'doctrineController'.$route;
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/controllers/'.$route.".php");
$controller = new $controllerName(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->setEntityManager(bootstrapDoctrine());
//echo "something";die(0); will show here but not after the next line
//  and only when I post values not on a get request
$controller->execute(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->redirect();
```

In the controller I have:

```
//JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper extends JController
class doctrineControllerTournament extends JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper{
     function __construct()
           {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->registerTask( 'show','show' );
              $this->registerTask( 'save','save' );
           }
     function show(){
        echo "works only on get requests, not on post";
        $model=$this->getModel('tournament');
        $view = $this->getView('show','text');
        $view->setLayout('default');
        $model->em=$this->getEntityManager();
        $view->data = $model->getTournamentAsJson();
        $view->display();
    }
```

Looks like a plugin messing with my post requests but don't know where to look for it. Client doesn't have a test environment set up and tried copying all 200+ thousand php files through ssh with a sql dump from the database but can't get it going locally.

Comment: Is there a difference in PHP versions on your localhost and live site?

Comment: @lodder I think I found what it is. In the layout I try to `var_dump($this)` that is causing an error. Got it locally as well. Guess I forgot to copy the layout so the local file was working (in a clean joomla install)